# Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type yearqtr

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
      Date     v1     v2
1   2005 Q4   5.0   6.52274 
2   2006 Q1   4.7   6.51802 
3   2006 Q2   4.6   6.36422


Code:-

 ggplot() + geom_line(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=v1,group=1,color="v1"))
```

I get an error because the date is in the **"yearqtr"** type. Please advice. I cannot convert the date in to year because i have quarterly data. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `zoo` package to convert.

```
library(zoo)
df$Date<-as.yearqtr(df$Date)
```

For plotting,

```
ggplot() + geom_line(data=df, aes(x=Date, y=v1,group=1,color="v1")) +
           scale_x_yearqtr(format="%YQ%q", n=5)
```